# How do I know which project is requesting a specific jar from Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

I'm using Eclipse and recently upgraded all my projects to use the latest version of a library.
However in the Maven repository I can still see the old version of the library.
I've deleted manually the old library from the Maven repository, but it keeps coming back.
I am sure all the projects in Eclipse point to the new version: I've checked all my pom.xml, I've used the "Dependency Hierarchy" tool, etc.

Is there a way to know which project is telling Maven to download the old version of the library?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)'s tree goal:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and filter using the [`includes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes) option which uses the pattern `[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`.

Answer (score 1):

Re: *"and I have many"*. Perform the following in the topmost directory:

```
 find . -name "pom.xml" -type f -exec mvn dependency:tree -f {} ';' | grep '^\[.*\] [-+\\\|].*'
```

Syntax details may vary from Bash to Bash.

Hint: **Try it in a bottommost project directory first** to ensure that it runs properly as intended. Since you have many projects it may take a while to finish and to recognize possible errors only then.

Comment: Thank you guys, appreciate the help, but I use Windows at work and I'm not allowed to install any software (I was thinking about Cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get a tree of all dependencies and then find out where the specific artifact is coming from.

You can pipe with grep to show only the related ones if you you are on linux/unix based os.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, appreciated, but it certainly is not an easy way. It looks like you have to do project by project (and I have many). Plus most of my pom reference poms in other folders and it's not able to process that either.

Comment: Just for everyone benefits: the issue with pom cross-reference was due to missing <relativePath> tag, which has never been a problem in the past, but it's required by the dependency:tree goal.